# Text object to Path: how to remove a single path from a double path produced when you use print method in Raphael js using cambam fonts?

Tags: javascript, php, svg, raphael, snap.svg

When I use the print method on Raphael js to convert text to path it produces a double path(an outline) of each character. I have searched on line and noticed that there are some fonts like: [camBam](http://www.mrrace.com/CamBam_Fonts/) fonts that seem to be true type fonts but they actually are tricking the font creators to see them as outline of a characters while they are putting 2 same lines on top of each other.   I was wondering If there is any way to programmatically (using js)  split those lines(paths) on top of each other and remove one of them?

Here is the svg code to an svg file that contains paths that are on top of each other and are the same for letter s (for example) :

**Update** : Sorry, here I've updated the right svg code:

```
<svg height="100%" version="1.1" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0, 0, 600,600"><desc>Created with Snap</desc><defs></defs><path d="M79.5111111111111,59.87405972222222C79.89444444444443,66.13517083333333,70.94999999999999,63.32405972222222,65.45555555555555,63.96294861111111C70.94999999999999,63.451837499999996,79.89444444444443,66.00739305555555,79.5111111111111,59.87405972222222C79,52.84628194444444,66.09444444444443,56.67961527777778,65.58333333333333,49.77961527777778C65.19999999999999,44.15739305555556,73.24999999999999,46.457393055555556,78.48888888888888,45.94628194444444C73.24999999999999,46.329615277777776,65.19999999999999,44.15739305555556,65.58333333333333,49.77961527777778C66.09444444444443,56.67961527777778,79,52.84628194444444,79.5111111111111,59.87405972222222C79.5111111111111,59.87405972222222,79.5111111111111,59.87405972222222,79.5111111111111,59.87405972222222" fill="#ff0000" stroke="#0000ff"></path><rect x="0" y="30" width="330" height="51" fill="none" stroke="#000000"></rect></svg>
```

**Update2:**
And [here](http://jsbin.com/pilonoyeqi/1/edit) is paths produced from both fonts

And if you manipulated it manually in inkscape or illustrator you can see that the letter s has 2 lines on top of each other that makes up that letter:

How can I remove one of the 2 lines(paths) using js? And if I have a whole text that has been converted to paths similar to the s character, how can I apply that removal function to all the text to make it single paths texts?

**Update3:**

I have the following code that tries to split the s path in half:

```
var sTotalpx = textpaths.getTotalLength();
var sSinglepath = Snap.path.getSubpath(textpaths, (sTotalpx/2), sTotalpx);
console.log(sSinglepath.toString());
```

And the path result is showing half of s and doubled line(paths)instead of the whole s with single line(path). Any workaround ideas please?!

**Update 4:**

I read somewhere that when you use svg editors:"  when using overlapping paths, use 'combine' or 'union' options to fuse the shapes together and remove overlaps."

How this is possible programmatically using js please?

Comment: I open the svg file you posted above on inkscape and there's not 2 paths in top of each other, just an outlined S letter. The exact same result as if you convert the font to path.

Comment: Thank you @crockz. Ok here I have an example html file that contains both versions of paths from a regular Arial font and cambam font: http://jsbin.com/pilonoyeqi/1/edit

Comment: @crockz. I am sorry I had put the wrong svg code first time, as you mentioned. I just updated that.

Comment: The problem is that they are not actually overlapping it's just like any other font, it closes the path but in this case follows the same path in a reverse direction. If you are using just one font I would suggest you edit the font js file.

Comment: Thank you @ crockz. I was thinking about your suggestion. But how would I know what part is the extra paths that I need to remove for each char? here is the example font.js file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/140225334/1CamBam_Stick_9_400.font.js

Comment: I was going to ask you to post the font file. I will have a look.

Comment: Thank you very much @crockz. Hopefully it doesn't need a lot of work to manually remove those unwanted paths!

Comment: @crockz. Did you have any time to look at the font,js file?!

Comment: Sorry Bayan I still didn't have time to go deep into it but from what I already saw the path doesn't start on the edges of the letter and it will always close itself when rendered, so that's maybe why it's doubled.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem in this definition (I added linebreaks to see better) :

```
M
79.5111111111111,59.87405972222222
C79.89444444444443,66.13517083333333,70.94999999999999,63.32405972222222,65.45555555555555,63.96294861111111
C70.94999999999999,63.451837499999996,79.89444444444443,66.00739305555555,79.5111111111111,59.87405972222222
C79,52.84628194444444,66.09444444444443,56.67961527777778,65.58333333333333,49.77961527777778
C65.19999999999999,44.15739305555556,73.24999999999999,46.457393055555556,78.48888888888888,45.94628194444444
C73.24999999999999,46.329615277777776,65.19999999999999,44.15739305555556,65.58333333333333,49.77961527777778
C66.09444444444443,56.67961527777778,79,52.84628194444444,79.5111111111111,59.87405972222222
C79.5111111111111,59.87405972222222,
79.5111111111111,59.87405972222222,
79.5111111111111,59.87405972222222
```

The last definition starting with a C is just wrong. This might be where your problem is coming from. You could try without this last part...?

This is the [W3C documentation for SVG paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands) that is useful to read it through ;-)

Let me know if that works for you

Comment: Thanks @ Kartsims, that s svg path is produced using the raphael js print method (using cambam fonts) which converts text to paths. even if I remove the last part it gives an error message. you can try to manually reomve the last part and see the error msg and it doesn't give me the half of the paths(single path s): http://jsbin.com/lexarazoti/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware it's an outdated question but looks like this is rather rare ... **I found this thread while searching for solution with very similiar problem**.
I needed single line font and used CamBam font, too. I used 'text-to-svg' to get SVG paths (probably the same results as with Raphael.js).

After some tests and reading I figured out that theese fonts are 'looped' to create [looking as] fillable (closed) paths, being more compatible with strictly systems. This is done by drawing path in reverse order.

**For simple, open chars this problem is not so hard** - SIMPLY it's enough to find 'central symmetricity point' in the middle of svg path sequence and drop the rest. **But this is not trivial problem, too.**

In this case it's a last point of middle(4-th) C[urve] command (78.48888888888888,45.94628194444444). From that point you can see mirror symmetric in control point's positions ... **but excluding the first point** of first C command next to 'reversing point'. There can be L[ine] command in the middle, too.

To get rid of error filling svg path must have attribute fill="none".

As mentioned eariler - it's quite easy with simple chars - **in many cases looping result can be different!** There **can be one, two or more closed loops followed with exactly** (or almost?) **the same loops but preserving  [original drawing] sequence** ('1a, 1b, 1a, 1b' or '1a, 1b, 1c, 1a, 1b, 1c'), not 1 by 1 copy ('1a, 1a, 1b, 1b') ... and probably (didn't checked this) mixed with 'symmetric looped' paths (to be divided) between them!

PS. This is theory ... I don't have ready, inplemented solution yet. I'll do it in a near future.

Answer (score 0):

To group two paths, you want to put them together under a parent `<g>` tag.

Comment: Thank you @Kartsims, Does that fuse the 2 paths for letter s(example above) and create a single path?

Comment: I don't get it, please send a jsfiddle or jsbin

Comment: Thank you @Kartsims. ok, here is a link to jsbin that might show what I mean: http://jsbin.com/lucenifujo/1/edit

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that the tag name didn't appear on my post !! I meant, group them under a `<g>` tag, like so `<g><path d="YOUR_1ST_DEF_HERE"></path><path d="YOUR_2ND_DEF_HERE"></path></g>`